# Hide li item if content matches another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have content inside the div "company-name", I also have a whole list of items which has the div "item-name". If the content inside 'item-name' matches the content inside 'company-name' (WORD FOR WORD), then I want to display:block; that li, otherwise the li should be HIDDEN.

Also if the "item-name" div is empty/blank, it should also be hidden.

```
<div id="company-name">ABC Corporation</div>

<ul>

<li>Content for this item - this list item should display:block; because the item-name matches the company-name
    <ul>
        <li class="location">Australia</li>
        <li class="industry">Pharmaceuticals</li>
        <li class="item-name">ABC Corporation</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>Content for this item - this list item should be HIDDEN - display:block;
    <ul>
        <li class="location">Australia</li>
        <li class="industry">Pharmaceuticals</li>
        <li class="item-name">XYZ Company</li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>Content for this item - this list item should be HIDDEN - display:block;
    <ul>
        <li class="location">Australia</li>
        <li class="industry">Pharmaceuticals</li>
        <li class="item-name">LMN Hardware</li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Show us where you are stuck ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the `item-name` elements and see whether its content is matching that of the `company-name`, if so show it like

```js
var cn = $('#company-name').text().trim();
$('li:has(li.item-name)').hide();
$('li.item-name').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text().trim() == cn;
}).parent().closest('li').show()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="company-name">ABC Corporation</div>

<ul>

  <li>Content for this item - this list item should display:block; because the item-name matches the company-name
    <ul>
      <li class="location">Australia</li>
      <li class="industry">Pharmaceuticals</li>
      <li class="item-name">ABC Corporation</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Content for this item - this list item should be HIDDEN - display:block;
    <ul>
      <li class="location">Australia</li>
      <li class="industry">Pharmaceuticals</li>
      <li class="item-name">XYZ Company</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

  <li>Content for this item - this list item should be HIDDEN - display:block;
    <ul>
      <li class="location">Australia</li>
      <li class="industry">Pharmaceuticals</li>
      <li class="item-name">LMN Hardware</li>
    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```